# Installing extensions on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How to install a extension on visual studio code using cli or cmd and also how to change the default terminal to any other like by default it uses cmd and i want to change it to cmder so please somebody help with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently vscode doesn't support installing extensions through cli.https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/691
You can specify the path to shell by editing `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` of your preference